# Why do I get spacing issues with fontawesome stars when using Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, font-awesome

I'm setting up a star rating system with Nuxt.js using fontawesome icons and for some reason whenever two different stars are placed next to each other, there's a weird whitespace that separates the two. For example, here is a rating with all full stars:

[image: full stars]

and here with an empty star:

[image: half star]

You can see the emtpy star is separated by some left-sided whitespace. This only seems to occur when using them in a vue loop so I'm sure it has something to do with Vue's virtual DOM but I'm not sure what it could be. My component looks like this:

```
<template>
<span class="stars">
    <span v-for="i in stars.full" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span v-for="i in stars.half" class="fas fa-star-half-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span v-for="i in stars.empty" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

full, half and empty are just an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view your source, you're likely to see this:

```
<span class="stars">
  <span class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

The empty star breaks to a new line, and this is what's causing the whitespace. You want all `<span>` elements on the same line to prevent whitespace between them, so try this.

```
<span class="stars">
  <span v-for="i in stars.full" class="fas fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span><span v-for="i in stars.half" class="fas fa-star-half-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span><span v-for="i in stars.empty" class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</span>
```

Ugly, but it works.